# Login option is not available. Please try another one

Tags: amazon-cognito

I followed the Amplify instructions to add a email login, now I am adding a Google login, and I'm getting this message instead:

Login option is not available. Please try another one

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation is not clear.

The Amplify CLI does not add a Google Identity Provider. It also changes the domain name unexpectedly.

You have to go in the AWS console, select your User Pool, and add the Google Provider yourself, and enable it in App Client Settings.

After I selected Google, and enabled it in Enabled Identity Providers, then it worked.

Also, it seems like the CLI wants to put all sign ins on the same web page, if you use signInWithWebUI,  but I think this is ok.

[image]

Comment: This can also likely happen when you detach and re-attach existing providers as well.

Comment: @webblover What to do in the case that you mentioned? Will the issue get auto resolved after some time or do we need to perform any action?

Comment: @AnandPadiya yes, if you do like that I said, it'll start working immediately. This is what I observed in my case. AWS doesn't need longer period for this detach/re-attach to take effect. This particular action gets effected immediately.

Comment: @webblover My issue was that I forgot to enable (check) the IDP from the App client settings after adding again.

Comment: Yes, you need to create it again; just drop and create again; If there are options for edit, edit it else delete and re-create it. It should work fine.

Comment: This 100% saved me from the round and round frustration, I had removed and re-enabled facebook and added it all back in but forgot to re-enable it again in the app client settings.

This is the first time i've tried using cognito and I've found it nothing but a faff to configure correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It fixed my issue by going to Cognito User Pool -> Federation -> Identity Provider -> select Google -> fill out "Google app ID", "App secret"(find those in your Google cloud) and "Authorize Scope"(profile email openid). -> Go to "App Client Settings" to enable "Google"

Note: you might find this video useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKA8qXINjkU, tho it is not specific to setting up Cognito through Amplify